# sqlite3 current directory tables can't be found

Tags: sqlite, directory

Based on the threads I read, I know if you launch sqlite3 when you're in whatever folder, then that's your current folder.

But I can't find any existing tables. It's like this:

```
XXXX/User/Folder$ ls
123.db   344.db
XXXX/User/Folder$ sqlite3
SQLITE version .....
sqlite> .tables
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must select database because tables exist in specific databases. In `Sqlite3` file system file represents separate database. So in your example you have two databases `123.db` and `344.db`. To select a database simply specify it to `sqlite3` cli:

```
$ sqlite3 123.db
sqlite> .tables
```

Now you should see the list of tables in database `123.db`.

Comment: worked! thanks a lot! If i need to change database, do i .exit and launch sqlite3 again? Thanks!